# How do I use the DateTime class?

Tags: ruby, datetime

Can someone tell me why I can sometimes use the DateTime class when a gem I use returns a DateTime object?

When I look it up in the documentation I don't see it listed under classes. Do I need to require something specific to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` is a class in the standard library. It isn't automatically included, like `Kernel`, for example, so you will need to `require 'date'` before it becomes available.

The [documentation for DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) can be found in the [Stdlib 1.9.3 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/).